# Error: Packet sequence number wrong for read replica

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

We have an environment with the following libraries and versions;

```
Python 3.8
Flask 1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.0
SQLAlchemy 1.2.10
PyMySQL 1.0.2
```

Normally, we run on a single RDS Mysql but because of the high load we needed to add a read replica and we have following configurations;

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = //DB URL
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 60
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 10
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = 30  # Default to 10
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT = 60  # Default to 30
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'read': Read Db URL
}
```

Before creating the read replica we would use db and session like;

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"expire_on_commit": False})
db.session.query(MyEntity).filter_by(id=self.id).all()
```

After creating the read replica we have added a read_session like;

```
read_engine = db.get_engine(bind='read')
session = db.create_scoped_session(options={'bind': read_engine, 'expire_on_commit': False})
read_session = session()
```

and started use it like;

```
read_session.query(MyEntity).filter_by(id=self.id).all()
```

but after this point, our application started to produce errors like `Packet sequence number wrong - got x but expected y` and `Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back` .

When I googled the error, I see that the reason of this error is multi-threading and it says every request should be handled in separate sessions but I wonder how it would work before creating the read replica. It seems SQLAlchemy uses the same session for all request because session is created with same way we did in SQLAlchemy instance. Related code in SQLAlchemy =>

```
def __init__(self, app=None, use_native_unicode=True, session_options=None,
             metadata=None, query_class=BaseQuery, model_class=Model):

    self.use_native_unicode = use_native_unicode
    self.Query = query_class
    self.session = self.create_scoped_session(session_options) # here is how session created in SQL Alchemy
    self.Model = self.make_declarative_base(model_class, metadata)
    self._engine_lock = Lock()
    self.app = app
    _include_sqlalchemy(self, query_class)

    if app is not None:
        self.init_app(app)
```

I wonder, what we did wrong and how we can create a session to use every where like SQLAlchemy did it?